# C# - How to fix error "missing server and user in credentials" when create new connection in VS2017

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a problem that I cannot load my database into visual studio 2017.
I used `entity framework 6.2` and I would like to load my database like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwE0Z.png) picture.

error said

> missing server and user in credentials

I have tried to add some reference but still the same problem.

Thanks Guys [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y7dh.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try delete your connection `localhost(member)` in `Server Explorer > Data Connections` first, the re-create a new one.